# Multiplying only numbers from file with fix number using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have space separated file which contain string as well as numbers. I wanted to only numbers with 2.

So far i was doing

```
!awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i ~/[^0-9]+/ $i=$i*2; print $0}'
```

I know my `print $0` statement is at wrong place but i don't know correct way.

Can someone help here ?

Answer (score 1):

multiply all the numbers by 2

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0==$i) $i*=2}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, but using ternary operator:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) (j=$i*2 ? j : $i) } 1' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Can you tell me whats wrong with my original code ?

Comment: @NikhileshSarishKulkarni Didn't test it but I'd assume you're missing an `if()` around `$i ~/[^0-9]+`.